# a question on partial isometry

Tags: operator-theory, operator-algebras, c-star-algebras, von-neumann-algebras

[image]
This is a statement from wikipedia.I don't understand why can we deduce that $C$ is a partial isometry if $A^*A=B^*B$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have
$$
\|CBx\|^2=\langle B^*C^*CBx,x\rangle=\langle A^*Ax,x\rangle=\langle B^*Bx,x\rangle=\|Bx\|^2.
$$
So $C$ is isometric on $\operatorname{ran}B$, and so on $\overline{\operatorname{ran}B}$. On the orthogonal complement, it is $0$ by definition. So $C$ is a partial isometry.

Comment: You mean that $kerC=\bar{ranB}^\perp$ ,but if $x\in \bar{ran(B)}$,why can we have $Cx\neq 0$?

Comment: Because $C$ is isometric on $\operatorname{ran} B$.

Comment: Let $M$ be a von Neumann algebra. If $x^*x=y^*y$, where $x,y\in M$. Does there exist relationship between $x$ and $y$? Can we deduce that $x=\lambda y, \lambda\in \Bbb C$.

Comment: No, not at all.  Just take any two isometries (in particular, any two unitaries).